# How can I start Jetty from IntelliJ on Windows?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I am using Windows 7 and IntelliJ 12. I downloaded Tomcat and I can use it just fine.
I want to use Jetty as well. But I wasn't able to.

Is Jetty coming with IntelliJ ?

Can someone guide me how to use Jetty? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ brings Jetty support, but [only in Ultimate Edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

If you do have it you'll need to create Jetty Run/Debug Configuration and fill in the required details.

[image: Jetty configuration]

Comment: But it says make sure you have installed Jetty. Which one should I download from here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Downloading+Jetty

Comment: I don't know what versions are supported by IntelliJ, Jetty 9 is pretty recent, so I would start with Jetty 8 first

Comment: Hello, I am getting a Duplicate config file paths found error, I googled it but could not find any solution. It says a "fix" button is provided, but it is not in Intellij 12.

Comment: Btw, I also have IntelliJ 10 installed in my computer. Maybe it is about this?

Comment: This error is about the configuration of Jetty Server Settings that you can see in the Run/Debug dialog. Note that if you press Configure for the server, it's already possible to select config files. Looks like you have them selected there and also added to the **Jetty Server Settings**, hence the duplicate.

Comment: Um why is there no http port option? wtf

Answer (score 5):

I have the same confusion before I fix it. Given my solution, hope it helps for somebody.

My environment: Jetty 9.1 and Intellij 13.0.1

**1**. note two points: the default port is 8080 unless you changed it; jmx mod must be chosen.

[image: intellij13-jetty9-run-debug-config1]

**2**. choose the war file to deploy in `Deployment` tab and setup your context path.

[image: intellij13-jetty9-run-debug-config2]

Comment: how do you change the port in Jetty settings in IDEA? do you have to edit the config file in Jetty/etc folder?

Answer (score 2):

One reason you might see the error is if you forgot to specify an artifact to deploy.  Go to the Run/Debug Configurations Deployment tab and add your artifact.  (Using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 ultimate)

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply use the maven plugin if your project is a maven project..

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then simply run jetty-run.