# IntelliJ idea - Jetty duplicate configurations found?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetty

I have IntelliJ Idea 12 and Jetty 9 on my Windows 7 machine.

I also have a sample JSF project which runs fine on Tomcat 7.0. When I try adding a runtime with Jetty, I get the error:

> Duplicate config file paths found

When I remove

> etc\jetty-jmx.xml

from Jetty Server Settings on this screen, I do not get this error but when I try starting the project, then I get:

> 2013-03-27 17:50:42.076:WARN:oejx.XmlParser:main:
>   FATAL@file:/D:/Jetty-9/start.d/ line:1 col:1 :
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Jetty-9/start.d/;
>   lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
>   file:/D:/Jetty-9/start.d/; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is
>   not allowed in prolog.    at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:996)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)    at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:220)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.(XmlConfiguration.java:138)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1209)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
>     ... 12 more
>
> Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
>          java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

So, how to configure Jetty properly on IntelliJ 12?

Comment: Did you check [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654476/how-can-i-start-jetty-from-intellij-on-windows#comment22219127_15654843)?

Comment: This [has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654476/how-can-i-start-jetty-from-intellij-on-windows#comment22219127_15654843) already by @CrazyCoder in [a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15654476/775715) asked by you.

Comment: Could it be that your .xml is malformed? Maybe it has a starting space or a BOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but resolved it this way on 
Intellij 2016.2.5 and Jetty 9.3.13

Be default in start.ini the following modules are Enabled

```
--module=ext
--module=resources
--module=server
--module=http
--module=deploy
--module=jsp
--module=websocket
```

And when i was Configuring Jetty in IntelliJ, i was adding some of the above to "Jetty Server Settings" section again, and so the error.

Only add "modules/jmx.mod"

[image]

Solution is to add the modules either here (IntelliJ > Run > Edit Configurations > Jetty server > local ) or in the "start.ini" file.

Answer (score 0):

So far I know, Idea 12 do not support Jetty 9. That's all.