# Simple web server to use with IntelliJ on windows?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ for a pure Javascript project (some HTML and javascript pages talking to someone else's web services).  Right now I am running the page directly from the filesystem, but there are limitations (like not being to write cookies).

Is there a simple web server I can use that will start and stop when I am debugging my project?  Like how visual studio will do with ASP.NET or Aptana does?

Thanks!

Comment: Vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7148. Right now you can install Python and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the project root directory from the [external tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html).

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at Jetty? [How can I start Jetty from IntelliJ on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654476/how-can-i-start-jetty-from-intellij-on-windows)

Comment: Great tip on using Python.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are doing, but install XAMPP, it is amazingly simple to use, although it supports PHP/PERL by default, rather than ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually I am not using ASP.NET or any special framework.  Just JavaScript and HTML talking to a public web service.

Answer (score 0):

if your want to use pure JS&HTML to do something maybe jQuery is a good choise
[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with lots of plugins.

if you would like to write some runnable program with Java, please use [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/)

Hope to help you :)